# Mysql: search and replace a part of the string '> <img' to '><img'

Tags: mysql, search, replace

I am trying to use search and replace and I've tried methods like this:

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE (
post_content,
'> <img',
'><img');
```

But this doesn't work. If just searching for `'> <img'`, it can only find a bit of offending cases, but if I search with wildcard `'%> <img%'`, then I can find all of them. It seems like just searching for `> <img` fails because it's a part of the string.

I've also tried something like this:

```
UPDATE wp_posts
SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, '> <img', '><img')
WHERE post_content LIKE ('%> <img%');
```

with no luck.

in this case, how do I execute the search and replace? please help and thanks!

Comment: How does it not work? What errors do you get?

Comment: i'd make a backup of that table first

Comment: "if I search with wildcard '%> <img%', then I can find all of them" So what's the question then?

Answer (score 0):

What if you change your replace criteria to `[space]<img` like below. Cause, essentially what I see that, you are trying to remove the space between `>` and `<img`

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE (
post_content, ' <img','<img');
```